# Converting Stored Proc to LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

**Please see EDIT at the bottom for current status of my question.**

I'm converting a stored procedure to LINQ to Entities and am making some progress. But I'm tripping up on the following:

In the WHERE clause of the SP, null values passed in are handled in the following way:

```
WHERE (@customerId IS NULL OR (CUST.CustomerID = @customerId))
```

So far, I have come up with the following:

```
return entities.Contacts
    .Include("Individuals")                
    .Where(c => customerId.HasValue && c.Individuals.Any(i => i.CustomerID == customerId.Value))
    .Select(c => c)
    .OrderBy(o => o.LastName)
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();
```

This is not working at all. 0 items are returned. Can anyone advise how this could translate to LINQ syntax. Thanks!

**Edit:**
I have almost got this out. The only fly in the ointment now is the ordering. For some reason the ordering is not being honoured. Here's some code:

```
public static List<Contact> GetAllTheCusts(string fName,
        string lName,
        string middleName,
        int? customerId, 
        string sort, 
        int pageIndex, 
        int pageSize)
    {
        AWEntities entities = Common.GetContext();

        int skipCount = pageSize * pageIndex;

        var contacts = entities.Contacts
            .Include("Individuals.Customer")
            .Where(c => customerId.HasValue
                            ? c.Individuals.Any(i => i.CustomerID == customerId.Value)
                            : c.Individuals.Any(i => i.Customer.CustomerID == i.CustomerID))
            .Where(c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(fName) || c.FirstName.Contains(fName))
            .Where(c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(lName) || c.LastName.Contains(lName))
            .Where(c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(middleName) || c.MiddleName.Contains(middleName));
            .Select(c => c);

        IOrderedQueryable<Contact> contactsOrdered = contacts.OrderByDescending(o => o.ContactID);;

        return contactsOrdered.Skip(skipCount).Take(pageSize).ToList();

    }
```

I'd be very happy and grateful to see the ordering resolved.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Filter by `customerId` only when its not null

```
var contacts = entities.Contacts;

if (customerId != null)
{
   contacts = contacts.Where(c => c.Individuals.Any(i => i.CustomerID == customerId.Value));
}

return contacts
    .OrderBy(o => o.LastName)
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Your code made me realise that my logic is all wrong. I need to go back to the drawing board. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Will following work?

```
Where(c => !customerId.HasValue || (customerId.HasValue && c.Individuals.Any(i => i.CustomerID == customerId.Value)))
```

Comment: I did try that. It did not get the result I was after.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've accidentally used `&&` where you mean `||` in the where clause.

Comment: The && was deliberate. If customerId.HasValue is false, the statement exits and there will be no filtering. That is the same logic as the Stored Proc. In the SP, if @customerId is null, the 2nd part of the statement is not evaluated and no filtering occurs.